# Create .img file for use with KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

How do I create a `.img` file or any disk image to be used with KVM?

Comment: go on - give us a clue - KVM?  In my line of work it is an acronym for "keyboard-video-mouse" !

Comment: [Kernel-based Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`qemu-img` should do the trick - for example:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 test.img 2g
```

Creates a 2GB `qcow2` format image.

See `man qemu-img` for more information

Answer (score 0):

you can create sparse file:

```
undefine@uml:/var/vm$ dd if=/dev/zero of=plik bs=1M count=1 seek=1000
1+0 przeczytanych recordów
1+0 zapisanych recordów
skopiowane 1048576 bajtów (1,0 MB), 0,00540732 s, 194 MB/s
undefine@uml:/var/vm$ ls -l plik
-rw-rw-r-- 1 undefine undefine 1049624576 lis  9 19:40 plik
```

and use it as image.